# How to select link of current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, href

I am trying to have my links in a menu styled when I mouse over them.
Then when the mouse leaves the link (without clicking on it) I want the current link to go back to being styled.

html:

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="title"><h1>Title<span id="Subtitle">Subtitle</span></h1></div>
      <nav class="cf" id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
        <li><a href="bio.html">BIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="current">HOME</a></li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
</div>
```

css

```
.current { color: #FFBB3F;}
```

js

```
$( "nav a" ).on('mouseover', function(){

    $( "nav a.current" ).removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
    });

$( "nav a" ).on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).removeClass("current");
    var pageURL = $(location).attr("href");
    $('a[href="pageURL"]').addClass("current");

});
```

but this is not working. if I do an alert

```
 alert(pageURL);
```

it gives me the path to the current page, and if I paste just an href

```
$('a[href="index.html"]').addClass("current");
```

it does style that link, but obviously I would want the current link to be styled. First time I try this. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just CSS, a combination of rules can get really close (perhaps close enough depending on how `#menu` is), see comments in CSS section:

```css
/*
  1. Color the current one if the menu isn't being hovered
  2. Color the current link if being hovered
*/
#menu:not(:hover) .current, /* 1 */
#menu a:hover {             /* 2 */
  color: #FFBB3F;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="title"><h1>Title<span id="Subtitle">Subtitle</span></h1></div>
      <nav class="cf" id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
        <li><a href="bio.html">BIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="current">HOME</a></li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
</div>
```

That CSS-only version has the issue that if you're not hovering a link but you are hovering the `#menu`, nothing is highlighted. I can't think of a pure CSS way to handle that, so a bit of JavaScript (see comments):

```js
// Set a class on #menu only when hovering a link
$("#menu")
  .on("mouseenter", "a", function() {
    $("#menu").addClass("link-hover");
  })
  .on("mouseleave", "a", function() {
    $("#menu").removeClass("link-hover");
  });
```

```css
/*
  1. Color the current one if the menu doesn't have the link-hover class
  2. Color the current link if being hovered
*/
#menu:not(.link-hover) .current, /* 1 */
#menu a:hover {                  /* 2 */
  color: #FFBB3F;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="title"><h1>Title<span id="Subtitle">Subtitle</span></h1></div>
      <nav class="cf" id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
        <li><a href="bio.html">BIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="current">HOME</a></li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This will add and remove the current class as well as style links being hovered over:

```js
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll("#menu a");


// Assign mouseover and mouseout event handlers to each anchor
for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++){
  anchors[i].addEventListener("mouseover", styleIn);
  anchors[i].addEventListener("mouseout", styleOut);
}


// This will hold a reference to whichever anchor has the current class
var currentAnchor = null;

function determineCurrent(){
  for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++){
    if(anchors[i].classList.contains("current")){
      currentAnchor = anchors[i];
    }
  }
}

function styleIn(e){
  determineCurrent();
  e.target.classList.add("hover");
  currentAnchor.classList.remove("current");
}

function styleOut(e){
  e.target.classList.remove("hover");
  currentAnchor.classList.add("current");
}
```

```css
a { text-decoration:none; }
.current { color: #FFBB3F; }
.hover { text-decoration:underline;}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="title"><h1>Title<span id="Subtitle">Subtitle</span></h1></div>
      <nav class="cf" id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
        <li><a href="bio.html">BIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="current">HOME</a></li>
      </ul>
      </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, but this way I have two links styled, the current one and the one I am hovering over. I wanted the current one to stop being styled if another was hovered. We wrote the comments at the same time. That's it

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I interpreted that to mean that the link should go back to its previous style.